# How to get jqgrid row index by some column value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to get jqgrid row id by some column value.

Example: i have one column called 'example_id' and i need jqgrid row id given that random 'example_id'.
Is that possible?

note: i don't click on the table, it's a parameter passed by url

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you fill jqGrid data in not full correct way. You wrote about "row index" instead of rowid. So I suppose that you don't specified `id` or rows in your input data. jqGrid need **always** assign unique value of `id` attribute of every row of grid (the `id` of `<tr>` elements). Because of "must to have" character of the information jqGrid have to assign some values like 1, 2, 3 as rowids. If your grid have column `example_id` with native unique information I would recommend you to use `key: true` property in the definition of the column in `colModel`. In the case jqGrid will use the value from the column to assign `id` attribute of rows of the grid. So you can solve your problem in the way.

Alternatively you can use [getCol](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method to get array of items like `{id:rowid, value:cellvalue}` where `value` property contain the value from `example_id` column and `id` contains the corresponding rowid. In the way you will . Using [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method you can easy analyse the array and get the ids of rows which contains some specific value in `example_id` column.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer... i explain what i want.
My clolumn has a unique information called example_id (primary key from db)
In this page i have one slide that contains the info int the table, imagine 4 regists (Ex: example:id = 1,12,13,25).
when i put the url with the id that i want, the slide should show the right record, so what e do is check that id on jqgrid and see what's that index (ex: 1,2,3,4)